# Settings Relationship Properties in Neo4J OGM

Tags: java, neo4j, relation, neo4j-ogm

I found out about Neo4j OGM yesterday and quickly made a new project to test out how it works. One problem I've come across is setting Relationhip properties as this is crucial for my project. Here's an example:

Room Node:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Room {

@GraphId
Long id;

@Property(name="name")
String name;

@Relationship(type="CONNECTS")
List<Room> rooms;

public List<Room> getRooms() {
    if(rooms == null)
        rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();

    return rooms;
}

public void setRooms(List<Room> rooms) {
    this.rooms = rooms;
}

public Room(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Room(){
}

public void connectsTo(Room room){
    this.getRooms().add(room);
}
}
```

Connects Node (Relation):

```
@RelationshipEntity(type="CONNECTS")
public class Connects {

@GraphId
Long id;

@StartNode
Room startMapNode;

@EndNode
Room endMapNode;

@Property(name="length")
int length;

public Connects(Room startMapNode, Room endMapNode){
    this.startMapNode = startMapNode;
    this.endMapNode = endMapNode;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Room getStartMapNode() {
    return startMapNode;
}

public void setStartMapNode(Room startMapNode) {
    this.startMapNode = startMapNode;
}

public Room getEndMapNode() {
    return endMapNode;
}

public void setEndMapNode(Room endMapNode) {
    this.endMapNode = endMapNode;
}

public int getLength() {
    return length;
}

public void setLength(int length) {
    this.length = length;
}

public Connects(){

}
```

}

Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new SessionFactory("at.htl.in110010.domain");
    Session session  = sessionFactory.openSession("http://localhost:7474");

    session.purgeDatabase();

    Room roomOne = new Room("TEST_ROOM_ONE");
    Room roomTwo = new Room("TEST_ROOM_TWO");

    roomOne.connectsTo(roomTwo);
    roomTwo.connectsTo(roomOne);

    Connects connectRelation = new Connects(roomOne,roomTwo);
    connectRelation.setLength(2);

    session.save(connectRelation);

}
```

Now as you can see I've set the length in my main method, but when I check the database under http://localhost:7474 it shows the relation between the nodes but says it has no properties.

Here is the console output:  http://pastebin.com/CByfmVcR

Any help in setting the Property would be very appreciated. 
Or is there perhaps a different/easier way of mapping objects to the neo4J database ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a relationship entity is the right thing to do as you have properties on the relationship. But this also means that your relationship between rooms is represented by `Connects`. 
So, `Room` should have a reference to `Connects` rather than to the other `Room` directly.

e.g.

```
@Relationship(type="CONNECTS")
List<Connects> rooms;
```

Here's a test that resembles your domain model:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/tree/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/ogm/domain/friendships and

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/ogm/integration/friendships/FriendshipsRelationshipEntityTest.java

I notice you're using neo4j-ogm 1.1.3. Please upgrade to 1.1.4 as it contains important fixes.

Comment: Ah yes that makes more sense now. Works perfectly thank you very much!